# URL encoding (umlauts) with redirecting (302 Moved Temporarily)

Tags: java, http, servlets, redirect

I am working on a servlet that takes a unique identifier as an input and either returns a document or sends a 302 Moved Temporarily redirect, if the document can be found on another server. The other server is a linux box with apache and exposes files through webdav. I have no control over this server.

Redirecting works fine, as long as there are no special characters (German umlauts) in the URL.

A problematic ressource looks like this `http://webfolder.company.com/projekt/übersicht.pdf`
When I copy and paste this URL into my browser (Chrome), I can open the file with no problem (the umlaut stays in the URL).

But when I send the redirect from the server side, the URL gets encoded into `http://webfolder.company.com/projekt/%C3%BCbersicht.pdf` and for some reasons I don't understand, this leads to a 404 - Not Found.

My servlet implementation gets the URL from the database (MySQL, UTF-8) and uses HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect method.

```
response.sendRedirect(remoteRessource);
```

(remoteRessource is a String). Using `curl` I can see the Location header being set, but Chrome (and Firefox) encode the URL into `http://webfolder.company.com/projekt/%C3%BCbersicht.pdf`, which leads to the 404 error.

```
< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
< Date: Wed, 06 Mar 2013 20:50:16 GMT
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Location: http://webfolder.company.com/projekt/übersicht.pdf
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 0
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=FA670C0DDA55593368A3285F54894153; Path=/; HttpOnly
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

What is the proper way to provide a redirect URL as-is to a browser that does not get encoded in any way? Thanks.

### Fix

Thanks to Julian Reschke's answer, I found out about the different encodings used by both servers. I now let Java/the URI class handle the encodings and things work fine.

```
URI uri = new URI(schema, host, path, null);
String location = uri.toASCIIString();
response.sendRedirect(location);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A likely reason is that the server running Apache+WebDAV expects an encoding different from UTF.8. ISO-8859-1 maybe?

Comment: I guess your are right. My ü translates to %C3%BC (utf8) whereas the webdav server wants %FC (ISO-8859-1).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use i18n package for internationalization of characters instead of sending localized characters [in this case german umlaut]

Take a look into http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html
which is what's happening in your case

And browse through [here](http://www.w3.org/International/URLUTF8Encoder.java) for encoding and [here](http://www.w3.org/International/unescape.java) for decoding

Comment: Thanks. But the URL is send to the browser is exactly as I want it to be and the browser does the encoding. And I would like to stop it from doing that.

Comment: I would recommend doing it the browser way as it takes care of localized characters. Suppose tomorrow you get a pdf with Japanese characters. Then your approach will break again. I hope you have taken this into consideration

Comment: I understand your approach. But the webdav server expects the Umlaut in the URL and only finds the document, if its there. If I encode the Umlaut, den WebDav server sends me a 404 Error and I have no control over the webdav server. Thus I would like use the URL as is without any encoding.

Comment: Try using `java.net.URLDecoder.decode("%C3%BCbersicht.pdf", "UTF-8")` in the servlet before checking for file in Webdav server.

P.S. I don't know how to stop browser from encoding this string, which is the original question.